# Netty BlockingOperationException

Tags: asynchronous, netty

I am using Netty 4.0.25 to write a network server.  I am testing it with a client program which is also written using Netty.

=> The client sends data to server continuously in a loop about 2 lac times, as below;

```
try {
  for(int i=0;i<noOfSubmit;i++){
    ByteBuf submit_packet= createSubmitsmPacket(components, PduConstants.SUBMIT_SM);
    f = ctx.channel().writeAndFlush(submit_packet);

    try {
         f.await();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("SENDING DATA "+count++);
    submit_packet = null;
  }
} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In the above code, if I remove the line "f.await()", then I cannot reuse the Bytebufvariable "submit_packet", by reinitializing it with next packet data, because the send operation "writeAndFlush" is asynchronous and thus it may still be using the submit_packet.  And if I use a new instance of submit_packet variable for each iteration in the for loop, I would be unnecessarily creating many objects and increasing the load on GC.

OTOH, if I put the line f.await(), then I keep getting *BlockingOperationException* after sending about 70K packets. I am assuming this is because the underlying TCP buffer might have become full.

My questions are the following:
1. Is it normal to get this BlockingOperationException ?

2. Is it safe to ignore the BlockingOperationException and keep retrying the send operation.  In this case, is it ok to wait for about half-a-second and retry, or can I retry immediately.  What is the best practice?
3. On the server side, I have to send response to the client packet.  I have to perform some business logic on the server, after *successfully* sending response to each incoming packet.  To achieve this, I am using f.await() on the server, and if success, then I am executing my business logic.

**adding stack trace for the blocking exception**

```
io.netty.util.concurrent.BlockingOperationException: DefaultChannelPromise@4ba6b85d(uncancellable)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.checkDeadLock(DefaultPromise.java:390)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.checkDeadLock(DefaultChannelPromise.java:157)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.await(DefaultPromise.java:251)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.await(DefaultChannelPromise.java:129)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.await(DefaultChannelPromise.java:28)
    at com.comviva.mbs.msdpv6.ecp_smpp_tester.EcpSMPPTestEncoder.sentSubmitPacketsToCP(EcpSMPPTestEncoder.java:146)
    at com.comviva.mbs.msdpv6.ecp_smpp_tester.EcpSMPPTestEncoder.unlimitLoop(EcpSMPPTestEncoder.java:137)
    at com.comviva.mbs.msdpv6.ecp_smpp_tester.EcpSMPPTestEncoder.createPacket(EcpSMPPTestEncoder.java:92)
    at com.comviva.mbs.msdpv6.ecp_smpp_tester.EcpSMPPTestEncoder.channelActive(EcpSMPPTestEncoder.java:57)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelActive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:208)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelActive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:194)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelActive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:758)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.fulfillConnectPromise(AbstractNioChannel.java:258)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:288)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:528)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:116)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: Please add the stack trace to the question.

Answer (score 0):

A solution to prevent the GC from collecting unnecessary objects would be using a ByteBufAllocator based on a pool, for example [PooledByteBufAllocator](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/buffer/PooledByteBufAllocator.html). The advantage of these Allocators are that the used objects return to the pool instead of being collected by the gc, but you need to make sure you don't use them after you released them.

You can use them in your handler as the following:

```
ByteBuf submit_packet = PooledByteBufAllocator.DEFAULT.buffer(initialCapacity, maxCapacity);
createSubmitsmPacket(submit_packet, components, PduConstants.SUBMIT_SM);
f = ctx.channel().writeAndFlush(submit_packet);
```

Where `initialCapacity` is replaced by the initial capacity of the returned ByteBuf, and the same for `maxCapacity`.

If you need more control over your ByteBuf, you should create a new instance of PooledByteBufAllocator and pass arguments to its [constructor](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/buffer/PooledByteBufAllocator.html#PooledByteBufAllocator(boolean,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) that state what to do.